# Segmentation fault in node.js harmony

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I run the following code with `--harmony` flag, I get `Segmentation fault: 11`.

```
'use strict';
var N = 100;

function test() {
    function recursive(n) {
        if (n < 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                let variable;
                variable += ' ';
            }
            return recursive(n - 1);

        }
    }

    console.time('Test');
    recursive(N);
    console.timeEnd('Test');
}

test();
```

Without `--harmony` flag, the code runs without any error.

**with `--harmony`**

```
$ node --harmony  recursion.js 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

**without `--harmony`**

```
$ node recursion.js 
Test: 8.161ms
```

My `node.js` version is `v6.6.0`. Pls help me if you have any idea, why I get the segfault.

Comment: update to a more recent version of node. In 7.4.0 everything works well...

Comment: These things are behind a flag for a reason :)